# Is there an quicker method (script/plugin) to export sidecar JPEG from Lightroom?

Tags: raw, jpeg, lightroom-3, macintosh, file-management

When I import RAW+JPEG in Lightroom I uncheck the option "Treat JPEG files next to raw files as separate photos" because I don't like the clutter this causes.
Sometimes I do want to have a sidecar JPEG of a certain photo. I then right click the raw photo in Lightroom and click on "Show in Finder". This brings me to the folder where I can find the JPEG file.

However, ideally I would like to use Lightroom export functionality to export the sidecar JPEG of a certain RAW file. In this way I could just select a batch of RAW files in LR, click export, select "sidecar JPEG" and then LR would copy the already existing JPEG files to a directory of my choice.

Is there such a way in the form of a plugin or script? Or even a native Lightroom way which I overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that by unchecking the "Treat JPEG files next to raw files as separate photos" option is that LR copies both RAW+JPEG to the destination drive, but IMPORTS only the RAW into LR. The JPEG files are not part of the LR database, and therefore there is no way to access or manage them from LR.

However, there is a better way to handle this, and that involves importing the RAW+JPEG into LR, but then instructing LR to reduce the clutter, while keeping the JPEG manageable by STACKING the RAW+JPEG.

So what you need to do is:

1. Check the box that reads  "Treat JPEG files next to raw files as
   separate photos" which will import both RAW and JPEG
2. Import RAW+JPEG into LR
3. Select all the images you imported
4. Choose Photo>Stacking>Auto Stack by Capture Time
5. Move the slider to 0. (the images were captured at exactly the same time)

This will then create a stack of each RAW+JPEG combo file, with the JPEG underneath the RAW. In order to choose just the JPEG, simply Filter on File Type: JPEG

Export as normal. If you haven't edited the JPEG, then LR will simply export the JPEG as is (it will go very fast).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

short answer: NO, none that I know of anyway

The JPEG image that you refer to as "sidecar JPEG" is NOT really a sidecar.  It is the in-camera processed JPEG.  It is not the same as the RAW file that you are using in Lightroom.  They might be the same "image" but the processing done on them are completely different.  The in-camera processing is a "trade secret" of your camera manufacturer and Lightroom doesn't know what was done to it by the camera.

If you want a quick JPEG export, just create an export preset with the settings that you want (size, quality, etc.) and use that export preset each time you need a quick JPEG of the Lightroom-processed RAW image.